# Cannot start Visual Web Developer, msvcr100.dll was not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer, visual-web-developer-2010

I recently had to do a PC Recovery on my Windows XP.  Visual Studio is still here, as are all my other programs.  Some programs worked, no problem.  Others, like Chrome, I had to reinstall, but once I reinstalled, all my bookmarks and addons came back.

But with Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, I'm having issues.  I try to start it, and it gives me the following error:

```
This application has failed to start because MSVCR100.dll was not found.  Re-installing
the application may fix this problem.
```

Okay, so I reinstall.  I try to redownload the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.  It tells me to download the .Net 2.0 Framework first.  I do that.  Additionally, I download the asp.net 4.0 Framework.  I try to run the Web Platform Installer, and it tells me to **download the .Net 2.0 Framework first again**!  I just did!  When I try to start Visual Web Developer, it's back to the same error -- the MSVCR100.dll error.

Any suggestions?  I've basically tried to do everything from scratch, but I'm at an impasse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are missing the MSVCR100.dll file which was probably removed during your PC Recovery.
Download it and paste it into your C:\Windows\System32 directory.
If you use a 64-bit version of Windows, you should also place msvcr100.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\

There is a possibility that you will be missing more dll files. If that's the case download them too and paste them in the same directory(s).

If you still get the same error try copying the dll file into your installation directory.

Try http://www.dll-files.com for dll files.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Babilicious ... I tried this, and now it's saying msvcr100.dll is not a valid windows image.  Ugh ... what a headache.  I'll try going back to figuring out why I can't get the Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3.0 to show Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express.  I'd just redownload the entire thing if it was there, but it's not there.  Silverlight, and a bunch of other things are there.

Comment: @JasonWeber Try to delete the dll from the system32 directory and have it only in your installation directory and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you Babilicious. I think I'm closer now. It's not giving me the missing .dll error, or the .dll is a bad image anymore. Now, it's just saying "Unknown error.".  I'm trying to reinstall Windows SP3, then ASP.NET 3.5, and ASP.NET 4.0 again.  Then, hopefully the MS Web Platform Installer will show Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, so I can redownload it.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555

This is the Visual C++ runtime you need to install. It will put msvcr100.dll back to the folder.

Comment: Thank you Lex.  I think I'm closer now.  It's not giving me the missing .dll error, or the .dll is a bad image anymore.  Now, it's just saying "Unknown error." and that's it -- it's not giving me any hint as to what the error is!  I think it's because when I did my PC Recovery, it deleted some files, but kept most of 'em.  I'll keep trying -- I'll try a complete reinstall if I could find a way to do it, since my MS Web Platform Installer doesn't show Visual Web Developer 2010.  Thanks again!